# Should I use a boolean variable to indicate whether a lock has been acquired?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently building a multi-threaded software (in C#), and I am not sure about my solution for a problem.

```
// isLocked is initialized at earlier stage
if (!isLocked)
{
   isLocked = true;
   // More code here
}
```

I know that the condition check is atomic, but i think its possible that another thread will enter the if block before 'isLocked' is assigned the 'true' value (thus creating an unwanted situation).

In Java, i could use AtomicBoolean's method 'compareAndSet' which is atomic, but C#'s equivalent 'CompareExchange' is not atmoic.

I tried using a `bool` in addition to the `lock` so that if the "locked" code is already being executed, other threads will bypass it. Is this a good way to do that, or is there a better way?

```
            Object myLock = new object();
            bool free = false;
            bool isLocked= actorsLocks[i];// Some Data structure 
            if (!isLocked)
            {
                lock(mylock)
                {
                    if (!isLocked)
                    {
                        isLocked= true;
                        free = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(free)
            {
                // actual method code here...
            }
```

Is there a more efficient solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are playing a very dangerous game here.  Atomicity is not the issue, you need thread-safety.  And none of this is thread-safe, isLocked and myLock are local variables, only one thread ever accesses them.  You have to worry about actorsLocks[i] instead.  Don't mess around when you get it this wrong, use lock in any code that accesses that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Java, i could use AtomicBoolean's method 'compareAndSet' which is
>   atomic, but **C#'s equivalent 'CompareExchange' is not atmoic.**

...Uh... yeah it is. Otherwise it would be completely useless.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

> If comparand and the value in location1 are equal, then value is
>   stored in location1. Otherwise, no operation is performed. **The compare
>   and exchange operations are performed as an atomic operation.** The
>   return value of CompareExchange is the original value in location1,
>   whether or not the exchange takes place.

Your solution is close. Make sure your lock object and all variables it protects are accessible by all threads. It won't do you any good to lock a locally-declared object. For example, `myLock` could be a class data member. It definitely should not be declared in the function. Same thing goes for `isLocked`.

```
class C
{
    int[] m_actorsLocks;  // *See below

    ...

    void WorkerFunction(int threadIndex)
    {       
        if (CompareExchange(ref m_actorsLocks[threadIndex], 1, 0) == 0)  // cmpxchg returns old value. If old value was false, it means WE locked it!
        {
            // do work

            // use cmpxchg to free the lock
            CompareExchange(ref m_actorsLocks[threadIndex], 0, 1)
            // I do this simply because I don't understand how C# caches outgoing writes
            // could possibly do m_actorsLocks[threadIndex] = 0; surrounded by Interlocked.MemoryBarrier()
        }
        else
        {
            // Threads who didn't get the lock come here...
            // If I understand what you're trying to do, you don't want the other threads to wait if they didn't get the lock.
            // So you probably wouldn't need this else clause...
        }
    }   

    ...

};
```

*If you store your locks in an array, you'll experience false sharing. Since arrays are stored contiguously, your locks will be on the same cache line... you would have the same performance as if you used 1 lock for everything. The grungy way to deal with this is to pad out your array. For example:

```
// If I want 4 locks 
int[] m_actorsLocks = new int[32];
// Now i only use index 0, 8, 16, and 24. The rest are just padding.
```

It's kinda messy and requires knowlege of your architecture... Better do some research on this one and maybe ask a seperate question.

Comment: Thank you! I have come through a page where they said ComapreExchange is not atomic. Good thing it is a mistake. But its pretty dirty to use ints instead of booleans. Is this the proper way of managing the situation?

Comment: Sure: CompareExchange<bool>(a, b, c)

I hadn't noticed that one when I looked at the page. BTW, there's a good chance that bools are internally represented as 32-bit integers. But I do agree with you that, semantically, it makes more sense to use bools.

Answer (score 1):

All you need in C# is:

```
object theLock = new Object();

lock(theLock)
{
    // Lock is yours, enjoy
}
```

Comment: This might not be the best solution, it depends on what's the lock for

Comment: I do not want the other thread to be stuck for the runtime of the method. I want it to check if a certain condition is met, if it is do the actual method code. else - continue with your run.

Comment: This is not the correct solution for what the OP is asking for. They don't want every execution to wait for the lock and execute the code. They want to ensure that only one thread runs it, and let other threads bypass it entirely.

Comment: In addition, it makes it look as if you can lock using an object created in the same scope as the `lock` statement. If someone sees this and does this bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the read of the bool is atomic but several threads can *read atomically* the bool and enter the 'if' block before the flag becomes false.
To do what you want (one thread only enters the 'if' block without blocking other threads) you can use kind of :

```
private long _n = 0;
......
if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _n, 1) == 0)
{
    // More code here, only one thread at a time.
    // Be carefull with exceptions.
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _n, 0); // Reset the flag for next running.
}
```

The Interlocked.Exchange is an atomic read&write: it will block all the threads, except one which will read '_n=0' and write '_n=1' *as an atomic operation*. The other threads will got 1 immediatly after the interlocked statment returns and they do not enter the block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both attempt to acquire the lock and find out whether you acquired it, in one atomic operation, use `Monitor.TryEnter(object)`.

`Monitor.TryEnter` returns true if the lock is acquired, false if it isn't. Only execute the "locked" code if `TryEnter` returns true.

```
public class SomeClassThatMultipleThreadsAccess
{
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public void MethodThatGetsCalledConcurrently()
    {
        if(Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject))
        {
            try
            {
                // only one thread at a time can execute this in
                // one instance of the class.
                // If _lockObject is static then only one thread at
                // a time can execute this across all instances of
                // the class.
            }
            finally // very important - if we don't exit then nothing else can enter.
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the object used for locking cannot be declared in the same scope in which it is used.

These both do nothing:

```
var lockObject = new object();
if(Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))

var lockObject = new object();
lock(lockObject)
{
```

because each thread will create a different object, so each thread will immediately acquire the lock. It won't prevent concurrent access to anything ever. There must be one object on which multiple threads attempt to acquire a lock.

Answer (score 0):

In few words: you're asking for trouble. Don't do that.

In more details, there are many factors you underestimate:

1. CPU conveyor optimization. This means that without proper "do not touch, multiple threads accessing" mark your CPU can modify execution order. And this may do very unexpected things that're absolutely legit in terms of single thread but can ruin your synchronization logic.
2. Compiler optimization. This can eliminate entire block of code according to Boolean value (and compiler has no idea the bool can be changed by another thread).
3. False sharing. This is more advanced thing and it can't change your program behavior. However, it can cause significant performance degradation because you read&write your hand-made locks at continuous array (that ruins core-level caches, fastest ones).

This is what can be named right out of the head. If think more, we can find more cons against hand-made thread sync mechanics. So, multithreading is like encryption: do not try to reinvent it, you're dangerously low-informed and would be cracked in minutes or even seconds.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But can you name specific changes I should use to follow your noted guidelines?

Comment: @ShahafNahmias, just use standard sync mechanics like Monitors, locks, concurrent collections.